The Number of $10$-Digit numbers Satisfying Certain Conditions
Find the number of $10$-digit numbers of the form ABCDEFGHIJ with distinct digits from $0$ to $9$ such that A > B > C > D > E and E < F < G < H < I < J.
There are variations of this question on the internet but not one like this. Now the logic of my solution is below, but it is very cumbersome. Does anyone know a more efficient way?

Don't choose the numbers smallest first than the second smallest.  Just chose any four and then any five numbers.  Put them in order after you have chosen them.  Counting these will fall into place surprisingly easily.

As is evident, $E = 0$, and we are left with digits $1-9$  to arrange.
Choose $4$ digits for ABCD, $\binom94 = 126$
Any such selection of distinct digits can be arranged in strictly descending order in only one way, and the remaining FGHIJ can be arranged in strictly ascending order in only one way,
thus # of such $10$ digit numbers is simply $= 126$

E = 0 since it is the least. Also, each number is defined by ABCD since FEHIJ can only be one sequence given you know the first 4 digits. By the constraints, D can be 1-6, C can be 2-7, B can be 3-8, and A can be 4-9. We will go through each case for D.

D = 6. This defines the rest of the letters giving only 1 number.

D = 5. C = 6 or 7. If C = 7 we get 1 number like above (The previous number will repeat in next answer). If C = 6, B = 7 or 8. 7 gives 2 options for A. 8 gives 1. This totals to 4 numbers.

D = 4 . . . Eventually this would brute force the problem, but this can't be the best way



Hint:  Don't try to solve right away.  Consider that we must have two sets.  One set is the four numbers that make $A,B,C,D$ and the other set is the five numbers that make $F,G,H,I,J$.  Don't worry about order.  Just the sets.  There are (by definition almost!) $9\choose 4$ ways to choose the first set.  Once you choose that first set... the second set can only be everything that is left.  And once we have the sets how many ways are there to order them?  Well, only one.  So...
